# Execute a randrange() having exceptions from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list:

```
l = [6,20,1,3,34]
```

I made a function which generates randomly numbers between 1 - 50:

```
from random import randrange
def rand():
     return randrange(1,50,1)
```

I would like to have the numbers from the list as  and i would like to run the function as many times i want and the output should have a value different than the values from the list above.

Hot to write my function with exceptions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
def rand():
    n = randrange(1,, 50)
    while n in l:
        n = randrange(1, 50)
    return n
```

the idea is to generate a random number until that number it is not in the list using a `while` loop

---

or you could use:

```
from random import choice

l = [6,20,1,3,34]
not_in_my_list = list(set(list(range(1, 51))).difference(l))

def rand():
    return choice(not_in_my_list)
```

another solution will be to generate a list with all the elements that are not in the list but are in your wanted range and then use `random.choice`

Comment: Thank you, from your examples i made the following test: a = [1, 2]

def rand():
    n = randrange(1,4,1)
    while n in a:
        n = randrange(1,4,1)
    return n

print("Result:",rand())


Result: 3

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
l = [6, 20, 1, 3, 34]
choices = list(set(list(range(1, 51, 1)))-set(l))
def rand():
    return random.choice(choices)
```

We just make a set of numbers from 1 to 50. Then the block numbers, ie a set of numbers we don't need. And subtract the 2 sets.

We're then left over with a list of numbers from 1-50 without the block numbers.

Now we just choose randomly from this new list named choices.